# OLE DB- eller ODBC-fel: [DataFormatError]External table is not in the expected format

Tags: powerbi, odbc, oledb, external

I have an excelfile.xlxs in a folder that is connected to Microsoft Power BI.
When I set up 3 tables from the file in relations it was all fine. When I try to update the small database this message occur "OLE DB- eller ODBC-fel: [DataFormatError]External table is not in the expected format". I can't find any solutions for it.

I have microsoft office 2016 32-system, AccessEngineDatabase 32-system and Power BI 32-system.

I'm not a programmer!
Please do anyone have any suggestions?

I just get my excelfile from a common shared folder on the server. And I have queries in Power BI to transform the data.

Comment: Where does the Excel file come from? is it an output from a source system, as sometimes the xml schema is not right, you have to load and save the file in excel that might fix it

Comment: I just get my excelfile from a common shared folder on the server. And I have queries in Power BI to transform the data.

Comment: I get this error and it could be that you've not specified the OLEDB connection properties properly but often there is no obvious explanation. Please try to open the files in Excel and resave them. If that works then there's something wrong with the structure of the .xlsx files that I have never found a solution to. It's something to do with the XML. If they still fail then have a look at how you're specifying the Connection String. Please report that here for us to see. Also open them in notepad or another text editor and make sure they're not HTML. Excel will open them. OleDB needs more info

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know how to get the connection string. In Power BI I just select connect to the folder where  the excel-file is. However it seems to work after I downloaded the file accessruntime_4288-1001_x86_sv-se.